# Python - np.dot in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I would to apply a np.dot with a "for loop" but an error : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape' appears...I have great arrays, for me it was the best way to treat my problem.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[ 1.15808013,  0.06208023,  4.05766652],
       [ 0.00440335,  1.10580116,  2.19747653]])


test=np.array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2., 2.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2., 2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4., 4.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  4., 4.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  6., 6.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  6., 6.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8., 8.],
        [ 7.,  7.,  8., 8.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.]]]) 

for i in range(test.shape[1]):
    for j in range(test.shape[2]):
        xtp = np.dot(M,test[:,i,j])
```

Comment: I have not got an error for your example. It works fine

Comment: There was no error on Python 2.7.3 with NumPy 1.6.2. Which versions are you using?

Comment: Can you post the _full_ traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to get all my coordinates :

```
frametemp = []

for i in range(test.shape[1]):
    for j in range(test.shape[2]):
        xtp = np.dot(M,test[:,i,j])
        frametemp.append(xtp)

frametemperature = np.asarray(frametemp)
```